# if statement to compare two cells in google sheets doesn't trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

This is probably a silly issue because I am new and am probably missing something simple.

I want to compare two cells that I used getValues() to get. **I'm wondering why my if statement doesn't trigger.**

This is my code

```
      for (j in phonesData) {
    var phonerow = phonesData[j];
    Logger.log('phonerow: ' + phonerow);
    for (k in unSubdata) {
    var unsubrow = unSubdata[k];
          Logger.log('unsubrow: ' + unsubrow);
      if (phonerow===unsubrow) {
         Logger.log('equals');
        phonesSheet.getRange(startRow + Number(j), 1).setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
```

And here are the logs with my commentary. It seems that the if should trigger!

```
[17-08-12 21:19:34:054 PDT] phonerow: (626) 234-7711
[17-08-12 21:19:34:055 PDT] unsubrow: (626) 235-3150
[17-08-12 21:19:34:055 PDT] unsubrow: (626) 235-3152
[17-08-12 21:19:34:055 PDT] phonerow: (626) 235-3150 <These are the same!
[17-08-12 21:19:34:056 PDT] unsubrow: (626) 235-3150 <These are the same!
[17-08-12 21:19:34:056 PDT] unsubrow: (626) 235-3152
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that it works this way.  If you got it from getValues() it's a 2 dimensional array.

```
function theirfunction()
{
  for (j in phonesData) {
    var phonerow = phonesData[j];
    Logger.log('phonerow: ' + phonerow);
    for (k in unSubdata) {
    var unsubrow = unSubdata[k];
          Logger.log('unsubrow: ' + unsubrow);
      if (phonerow[0]===unsubrow[0]) {
         Logger.log('equals');
        phonesSheet.getRange(startRow + Number(j), 1).setValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I actually figured it out using this version.

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r0=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var r1=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=r1.getValues();
  var vB=r0.getValues();
  for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++)
  {
    for(var k=0;k<vB.length;k++) 
    {
      Logger.log('vB[' + k + '][0]=' + vB[k][0] + ' and ' + 'vA[' + j + '][0]=' + vA[j][0]);
      if(vA[j][0]==vB[k][0]) 
      {
         Logger.log('equals');
      }
    }
  }
}
```